# Wiring SIX IR_LEDS

Tags: led, infrared

I am trying to wire six IR LEDS with three parallel sets of two IR LEDS in series. Each set has its own current limiting resistor and they all share a common **5V** line at their anode and are connected together to a Mosfet at the cathode. Is there something wrong with this implementation or can it be improved in any way?[image]

[image]

Comment: You've forgotten to tell us the supply voltage. Add it into the question using the [edit] link ...

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the feedback. I have made the necessary changes

Comment: It can be improved with design specs , Temp Range. Tolerance analysis.  And temp rise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your circuit (assuming it works out thermally). Plenty of voltage across the dropping resistors so the current is reasonably constant. The MOSFET is 'okay', a beefier one wouldn't hurt, xx2302 for example, which is usually not much different in price.

Maybe it could be improved by dumping the resistor droppers and using a LED boost chip such as the [AP3031](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Diodes%20PDFs/AP3031.pdf). There are other options which might be better under your particular conditions, maybe there are fancier ones which replace the diode with a synchronous MOSFET for better efficiency, for example.

That plus one small  (4.7uH) inductor, a Schottky diode, a current-setting resistor, and a  couple ceramic capacitors yield constant current control about 80% efficiency. All your LEDs can go in series, since that only adds up to about 8V. It also has a control voltage input so you can get rid of the MOSFET.

80% efficiency means ~200mA from the 5V supply rather than 300mA.

But really there's nothing wrong with your circuit as-is, and it won't contribute electrical noise like a 1MHz switcher might.

Comment: Wonderful answer, I think. Covers a lot of bases, quickly. I'd have written far too much with less effect. Thanks!